# Value always return 0 where it should return number of row inserted

Tags: php, android, mysql, return, toast

I have two table, one is `Information` and the other is `WorkForce`

**Information**

[image]

**WorkForce**

[image]

The twf `column` in **WorkForce** is used to get the `id` of **Information**, which suppose return as 1, but it return value 0. If the `id` in **Information is** 5, `twf` should be 5 too.

Firstly I use the `a` to represent the number of selected row and then add the parameter of `a` into `addWorkForce`. The `toast` always display 0 .

```
  a=addInformation(name,weather,date2,status,first1[1],last1[1]);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  addWorkForce(Sub, NoP, NoH,a);
```

**addInformation function**

```
  public long addInformation( final String name, final String weather, final String date2, final String status, final String timeIn, final String timeOut)
    {
        class AddInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(WorkDetailsTable.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
                data.put(Config.KEY_USER_NAME,name);
                data.put(Config.KEY_WEATHER,weather);
                data.put(Config.KEY_DATE,date2);
                data.put(Config.KEY_STATUS,status);
                data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEIN,timeIn);
                data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEOUT,timeOut);
                RequestHandler rh=new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.ADD_INFORMATION,data);
                return  result;
            }
        }

         AddInfo ru = new AddInfo();
         ru.execute(name,weather,date2,status,timeIn,timeOut);

        return 0;

    }
```

Can someone help me to figure out the problem ?

**addInformation.php**

```
<?php 

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        //Getting values
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $weather = $_POST['weather'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
                $status = $_POST['status'];
                $timeIn = $_POST['timeIn'];
                $timeOut = $_POST['timeOut'];

        //Creating an sql query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO information(name, weather, date, status, time_in, time_out) VALUES ('$name','$weather','$date', '$status', '$timeIn', '$timeOut')";

        //Importing our db connection script
        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        //Executing query to database
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo 'Information Added Successfully';
        }else{
            echo 'Could Not Add Information';
        }

        //Closing the database 
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

This is how I used the code to get the row inserted into sqlite and it works

```
 a = ts.insertTimeSheet(name, weather, date2, status, first1[1], last1[1]);
```

**TimeSheet**

```
 public long insertTimeSheet(String name, String weather, String date, String status, String TimeIn, String TimeOut) {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Name, name);
        values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Weather, weather);
        values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Date, date);
        values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Status, status);
        values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.TimeIn_Info, TimeIn);
        values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.TimeOut_Info, TimeOut);
        return database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, null, values); // if the id in Information is 5, twf display 5 too
```

Comment: `echo 'Could Not Add Information';` this John does not help you if there is an error in your query. You need to get the real error. Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` should there be any.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no error in my code. I just want to know how to get the number of row of the table Info to WorkForce

Comment: It should return 1 to column workForce. If there are 2nd row, then display 2 in workForce twf...

Comment: *"I just want to know how to get the number of row"* (as per a comment elsewhere). This seems to be Android related syntax and I can't help you with that. In SQL, you can try using `mysqli_affected_rows()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php but I'm not entirely sure if that's what your question is about.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just want  the number of row returned to `a` only...

Comment: Debug it, it is returning value as `0` before completing `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per your code to add information:

```
a=addInformation(name,weather,date2,status,first1[1],last1[1]);
```

Here, you are calling `addInformation` on main thread and hold the return value to variable a. But the problem is, your actual implementation of adding information is done in `doInBackground` of `AsyncTask` which actually does the job on a worker thread (async call) and so you will always get the default value for a=0 (as a is long).

What you need to do is to move your code to `onPostExecute` function of `AsyncTask` like below:

```
public void addInformation( final String name, final String weather, final String date2, final String status, final String timeIn, final String timeOut)
    {
        class AddInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(WorkDetailsTable.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                addWorkForce(Sub, NoP, NoH,a);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
                data.put(Config.KEY_USER_NAME,name);
                data.put(Config.KEY_WEATHER,weather);
                data.put(Config.KEY_DATE,date2);
                data.put(Config.KEY_STATUS,status);
                data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEIN,timeIn);
                data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEOUT,timeOut);
                RequestHandler rh=new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.ADD_INFORMATION,data);
                return  result;
            }
        }

         AddInfo ru = new AddInfo();
         ru.execute(name,weather,date2,status,timeIn,timeOut);

    }
```

There is another approach to use callbacks. Implement an interface and after completion of your AsyncTask, you can send callback to do another job.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue is coming from this line

```
return 0;
```

Your addInformation method returns a long with a value of 0 every time. If you want it to return some other number you will need to change that line.

Edit: 
To keep track of your row, add another parameter to your method header

```
public long addInformation(int rowId, final String name, final String weather, final String date2, final String status, final String timeIn, final String timeOut)
```

Comment: what value should I use?

Comment: Whatever value you are expecting it to return. If you want the id of the row, you will need to add that as a field to your class, so that it can be a part of your constructor and then be used to return at the end of the method.

Comment: make twf as `foreign key` ?

Comment: That is one way to get the right numbers in your SQL tables, however that won't solve the issue of the Toast notification always being 0

Comment: can you please tell me how to add the id as field of my class ?

Comment: then return rowId ? no need change php file ?

Comment: Correct, return rowId. Also you haven't posted any PHP code yet so I don't see any need to modify anything

Comment: If you have question about PHP code I would recommend posting another question. Your issue here has already been resolved as you asked how to make sure the Toast notification was not always 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99325/discussion-between-john-joe-and-bhooks).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the lastInsertId() mysql function after the row inserted in first table.that is (Information)
store the value of lastInsertId() in some variable and use that variable at that time when you insert row in next table. that is (WorkForce)

Comment: can you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 4):

Since [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is an asynchronous task, the `return 0;` line in your `addInformation` method always comes first, that's why you got **0** instead of ***"number of row inserted"***.

You should update your code as the following, please pay attention to my comment `// MOVE addWorkForce HERE`.

```
public void addInformation( final String name, final String weather, final String date2, final String status, final String timeIn, final String timeOut)
{
    class AddInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(WorkDetailsTable.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            addWorkForce(Sub, NoP, NoH, Long.parseLong(s)); // MOVE addWorkForce HERE
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
            data.put(Config.KEY_USER_NAME,name);
            data.put(Config.KEY_WEATHER,weather);
            data.put(Config.KEY_DATE,date2);
            data.put(Config.KEY_STATUS,status);
            data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEIN,timeIn);
            data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEOUT,timeOut);
            RequestHandler rh=new RequestHandler();
            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.ADD_INFORMATION,data);
            return  result;
        }
    }

     AddInfo ru = new AddInfo();
     ru.execute(name,weather,date2,status,timeIn,timeOut);  
}
```

Then, you only need to call

`addInformation(name,weather,date2,status,first1[1],last1[1]);`

Of course, make sure `Sub, NoP, NoH` variables are accessible inside `AddInfo` class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: so use `s` instead of `a` ?

Comment: Yes, because `return  result;` inside `doInBackground` will be `s` inside `onPostExecute` :)

Comment: You can read more at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html, `The 4 steps` section for more info about AsyncTask

Comment: ok, but I get wrong 4th arguments type as my `s` datatype is String :/

Comment: Ah, then you can use `Integer.parseInt(s)`, however, should catch `NumberFormatException` too

Comment: If it's `long` type, you can use `Long.parseLong(s)` instead

Comment: Thanks. If I delete the row 1 in `information` and then insert the data again, the ID will be 2 since I using `auto-increment`. Will the `twf` in work force will be 2 also or 1 ?

Comment: About the logic (table's field) inside your database, I have no idea :). You can try

Comment: Thanks, will try later .:) Hope it will be 2, not 1 :(

Comment: `The number of rows` is different from the `row number/id`, I think. `The number of rows` should be the number of records exists inside your table, right?

Comment: The `twf` should always same with the `id` in information

Comment: Please post `logcat` information so that I can check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99509/discussion-between-john-joe-and-bnk).

Comment: can we continue this ?

Comment: Sorry, I am at my holiday. However, as in our previous chat session, you should check where PHP reponses `twf` value to android and where android gets that value